# filtering dataframe based on threshold value with known maximum columns and column ordering constraints

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, memory-efficient

I have a dataframe of shape `(7985, 3048)`, formatted something like below:

```
image_name    col1_ID    col2_ID    col3_ID    ...  colN_ID      # header
rdr_001_101   0.00342    0.00015    0.10094    ...  0.34210      # prob. distrib
rdr_001_133   0.00432    0.00025    0.01465    ...  0.22108      # prob. distrib
...
...
rdr_003_167   0.07543    0.00576    0.07523    ...  0.73421      # prob. distrib
```

Now, for each image, I want to select only 100 columns and their corresponding indices, out of these 3047 values. The 100 columns should be chosen based on the values in the columns (i.e. choose the columns with maximum values, until we reach the count of 100).

**Constraint**: The ordering of column matters (i.e. it should stay in the same order in the output as in the input). Please see sample input/output below for an example.

I have a loop based solution (using df.iterrows) but it's super slow and it seems it's not a recommended method in general. Further, this is a simple example whereas my actual dataframe could have more rows.

what are other possible (faster) alternatives?

---

Sample input, with only 5 columns:

```
image_name    col1_ID    col2_ID    col3_ID   col4_ID   col5_ID
rdr_001_101   0.00342    0.00015    0.10094   0.34210   0.27651
rdr_001_133   0.43211    0.00025    0.01465   0.22108   0.00123
rdr_003_167   0.07543    0.25761    0.07523   0.01148   0.00341
```

Expected output, with 3 columns as threshold:

```
col3_ID    col4_ID    col5_ID
col1_ID    col3_ID    col4_ID
col1_ID    col2_ID    col3_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html?highlight=argsort#numpy.argsort) with 1d array by length of columns first by `np.arange(len(df.columns))`, then indexing top N values, sorting them by `np.sort` and last indexing columns names `cols`:

```
df = df.set_index('image_name')
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
N = 3

print (np.arange(len(df.columns)))
[0 1 2 3 4]

print (np.arange(len(df.columns))[np.argsort(-df.to_numpy())[:, :N]])
[[3 4 2]
 [0 3 2]
 [1 0 2]]


arr = np.sort(np.arange(len(df.columns))[np.argsort(-df.to_numpy())[:, :N]], axis=1)
print (arr)
[[2 3 4]
 [0 2 3]
 [0 1 2]]

c = cols[arr]
print (c)
[['col3_ID' 'col4_ID' 'col5_ID']
 ['col1_ID' 'col3_ID' 'col4_ID']
 ['col1_ID' 'col2_ID' 'col3_ID']]
```

Last convert output to `DataFrame` if necessary:

```
c1 = [f'top{x+1}' for x in np.arange(N)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(c, index=df.index, columns=c1)
print (df1)
                top1     top2     top3
image_name                            
rdr_001_101  col3_ID  col4_ID  col5_ID
rdr_001_133  col1_ID  col3_ID  col4_ID
rdr_003_167  col1_ID  col2_ID  col3_ID
```

---

If possible sorting columns names helper `1d array` is not necessary:

```
df = df.set_index('image_name')
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
c = np.sort(cols[np.argsort(-df.to_numpy())[:, :N]], axis=1)
print (c)

[['col3_ID' 'col4_ID' 'col5_ID']
 ['col1_ID' 'col3_ID' 'col4_ID']
 ['col1_ID' 'col2_ID' 'col3_ID']]
```